# Changing CSS when changing select

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

This is currently working. But what I'm wondering is why this isn't affecting the CSS of every `.container` within a `.filteritem`. It's only finding the very first one on the page whereas I want to to change everything `.container` within a `.filteritem`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'alltopics') {
            $('.filteritem').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            var elems = $('.filteritem[data-aa_eventtopic="' + this.value + '"]');
            $('.filteritem').not(elems).closest('.filteritem').fadeOut(500);
            elems.closest('.filteritem').fadeIn(500);

            //HERE
            $('.filteritem').each(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.container').filter(':visible').first().css({
                        borderTop: 'none',
                        paddingTop: '0px'});
                }, 501);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: .first() is probably the culprit here. Plus, technically it looks like it is targeting all .container regardless of its parent. maybe you wanted $(this).find('.container')

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to get rid of that [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) call

Comment: I only want to effect the first child.

Comment: Then you can do .children().first() , because first() reduces whatever set of element to the first one, does not return the first child.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the .first() there...

```
$('.filteritem').each(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){$('.container').filter(':visible').first().css({borderTop : 'none', paddingTop : '0px'});},501);        
});
```

You're telling it to target only the first .container, and more so, not even a container within the current .filteritem. Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
$('.filteritem').each(function() {
   setTimeout( function(){$(this).find('.container').filter(':visible').css({borderTop : 'none', paddingTop : '0px'});},501);        
});
```

** UPDATE **

and because you only want the first CHILD of the container:

```
$('.filteritem').each(function() {
   setTimeout( function(){$(this).find('.container').filter(':visible').children(':first').css({borderTop : 'none', paddingTop : '0px'});},501);        
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I fixed it by combining them.           elems.closest('. filteritem').fadeIn(250,function(){
          $('. filteritem').each(function() {
            $(this).find('. container').filter(':visible').first().css({borderTop : 'none', paddingTop : '0px'});
          });
      });